# Pact Broker UI not visualizing usage of matchingRules and generators

Tags: pact, pact-broker

When my PACT contains **type** matchers only instead of matching concrete values of Strings for example, my PACT Broker UI does not visualize that and thus, raising the impression for the provider that I do expect concrete values from the provider:

This is a part of my PACT:

```
"response": {
        "body": {
          "content": {
            "description": "Example description",
            "expensive": false,
            "goodRated": false,
            "price": 100,
            "productId": "string",
            "rating": 100,
            "title": "string"
          },
          "contentType": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
          "encoded": false
        },
        "generators": {
          "body": {
            "$.price": {
              "max": 2147483647,
              "min": 0,
              "type": "RandomInt"
            },
            "$.productId": {
              "size": 20,
              "type": "RandomString"
            },
            "$.rating": {
              "max": 2147483647,
              "min": 0,
              "type": "RandomInt"
            },
            "$.title": {
              "size": 20,
              "type": "RandomString"
            }
          }
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": [
            "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
          ]
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "body": {
            "$.description": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$.price": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "number"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$.productId": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$.rating": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "number"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$.title": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

And this is how my broker shows it:

[image]

Other than the values shown, like 100 for `price` and `rating` or "string" for `title` and "Example description" for `description`, I do not find any hint that none of these values are exact matches but all type matches only.
Do I not find it or something? I suppose this is a lack of feature of the UI?

Comment: solution candidate: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby/pull/129 it was noticed already and attempted, but then discarded due to lack of resources

Comment: This is shown in Pactflow.io UI, though